# Как хранить всю инфу сокетов Socket.io в redis?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, redis

Есть 2 сервера с одним и тем же кодом node.js, есть балансировщик, на обоих нодах используется socket.io с адаптером redis-adapter. В адаптере хранится какая то инфа, но не сокеты. Мне надо слать сообщение от одного пользователя другому, т.е. от одного сокета другому, а они могут находиться на разных нодах. Еще ситуация усугубляется тем, что если коннект был на одной ноде, а дисконект отсылается на другую, то сокет на первой остается в памяти. Было бы здорово, если бы все сокеты хранились в одном месте, и если происходит дисконнект неважно на каком сокете, он бы удалял его в редисе и было бы счастье.
Сохранение объекта socket в редис к сожалению не получается из-за ссылок на себя, или что то в этом роде (редис ругается). 
Подскажите пожалуйста как быть ?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать мидлвару, которая будет хранить в сессии так же id сокетов сопоставляя с пользователями. С монгой я  использовал модули express, passport, mongoose, expressSession и express-socket.io-session:

```
// Configuring Passport
    var passport = require('passport');
    var expressSession = require('express-session')({secret: 'catonkeyboard'});
    app.use(expressSession);
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    var sharedSession = require("express-socket.io-session");
    io.use(sharedSession(expressSession, {
        autoSave:true
    }));
```

Тогда, если пользователь зареган и открывает сокет-соединение с сервером, его данные, включая id сокета хранятся в заданной коллекции сессии бд. На локалке все работало отлично, модули обновляли инфу в монге в колекции сессий прямо находу, а в объектах сокетов io.sockets.connected[i] сохраняли данные пользователя, если у него был куки авторизации действующей сессии. В вашем случае нужно что-то подобное. Уверен, вам тоже может помочь этот модуль https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Буду разбираться :)